# Scala Spark RDD current number of partitions

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How do you determine the number of partitions of an arbitrary RDD in Scala?

I know PySpark RDD has getNumPartitions defined in its API, but I can't locate the equivalent on the Scala side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `rdd.partitions.length`.

Answer (score 5):

At least in Spark 1.6.1 this works

```
rdd.getNumPartitions()
```